Hilt Unsupported metadata version in Kotlin error
I tried to run my code in Kotlin 1.9.0 with the plugins
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

and dependencies as below
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.48")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03")
    kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.2.0")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.2.0")

    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:28.0.0'`
}

When I migrate to kotlin_version = "1.9.0", it just errors out stating
error: [Hilt]
  Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0
    at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.metadataOf(KotlinMetadata.java:200)
    at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.from(KotlinMetadata.java:182)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1220)
    at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadataFactory.create(KotlinMetadataFactory.java:54)
[Hilt]


Please [edit] your question and also provide the project level gradle file.

You need to replace the plugin id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin' with this (probably also in your root gradle file that you didn't show us):
id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'

Then you just need to remove the following dependencies and it should be working again:
implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03")
kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.2.0")


If this answered your question you can accept it by ticking the check mark next to it.
